# Special Minkowski Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $a_{i},b_{i},c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. Suppose that

$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i})^2)^{1/2} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}(b_{i})^2)^{1/2} + (\sum_{i=1}^{n}(c_{i})^2)^{1/2}$.

Taking $\lambda_{i} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. Show that

$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}\lambda_{i})^2)^{1/2} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}(b_{i}\lambda_{i})^2)^{1/2} + (\sum_{i=1}^{n}(c_{i}\lambda_{i})^2)^{1/2}$.

I proved the case $n=1$, but I failed in case $n=2$ and general case.

Hints or solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the $\lambda_i$ is fixed to be the same for all $i$, then you're inequality is true by homogeneity... did you perhaps mean that?

Comment: I am guessing that the missing bit of information is that $\lambda$ should be normalized, i.e that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i = 1
$$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar That's not enough to make it hold, try for example $\lambda_1 = 1/10\,$, $\lambda_2=9/10$ with the numbers posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition does not hold true in general for $n \ge 2\,$.

Counterexample for $n=2\,$: let $\,a_1=2, a_2=9\,$, $b_1=c_1=3, b_2=c_2=4\,$, which satisfy:

$$
\sqrt{2^2+9^2} = \sqrt{85} \;\;\color{red}{\lt}\;\; 10 =  \sqrt{3^2+4^2} + \sqrt{3^2+4^2}
$$

But for $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{10}$ and $\lambda_2=1\,$ the inequality is reversed:

$$
\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{10}\right)^2+9^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2026}}{5} \;\;\color{red}{\gt}\;\; \frac{\sqrt{1609}}{5} =  \sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^2+4^2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^2+4^2}
$$